# jQuery - validate - how to set dynamic messages to dynamic validation rules?

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to set a dynamic rule to a set of elements (multiple inputs having class  = website) with a remote validation to check the validity of entered url. 
The problem is that I hardly managed to set a dynamic error message containing the value entered with a link to test the url, like this :

"The web site doesn't exist : url entered with link ".

The only way I found is to make the remote method set the message and return it in JSON and then I set the input title in the dataFilter. But the problem is that I put  html tags in  an HTML attribute (title). That works but is not very correct.
Notice that if i use variable in the message property constructor, the value returned is the one just after DOM complete, not the value entered (see comments)

```
$.each($(".website"), 
                function() {

                    var elementId =  $(this).attr('id');

                    $(this).rules("add",{

                        remote : 
                          {   
                              url: 'check-url.php',
                              type: "post",
                              data:
                              {
                                  prefix: function() {
                                    return  $("#"+ elementId).prev().val();
                                }
                              },
                            dataFilter: function (data) {
                                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                                $("#"+elementId).attr('title',json.error);
                                return json.msg;
                            },// message not OK (value on DOM complete)
                            messages : 'The web site doesnt exist : ' + $("#"+ elementId).prev().val() 

                          }
                    });
                }
            );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".website").each(function () {

    var $el = $(this);

    $el.rules("add", {
        remote: {
            url: 'check-url.php',
            type: "post",
            data: {
                prefix: function () {
                    return $el.prev().val();
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            remote: function () {
                return 'The web site doesnt exist : ' + $el.prev().val();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt'work : the data sent is the value just after DOM is complete  because $el is something like interpreted on loading not on event. That's why I use the eval-like hint with # + id.Secondly the message is not considered event with  return , I have the default message.

Comment: @user3464543 missed to add a `return` in the message callback.. also make sure that the element `$el.prev()` is correct

Comment: The message is not considered even with  return and a static message (only text): I have the default message "Please fix this field". I had already tried all the different syntaxes provided in the doc without success.

Comment: Did anyone got a fix for this issue. If yes, kindly post it.